# Remove unnecessary HTTP headers using apache

Tags: java, apache, jsp, http-headers, tomcat7

I have a requirement in my application where a header other than default one sent in http request should be suppressed. Right now in my application when i send a request i am able to attach custom header fields.

Is there a way in apache tomcat configuration settings which will suppress headers other than default ones ? , i tried checking few sites, i found how to remove headers in response

http://www.shanison.com/2012/07/05/unset-apache-response-header-protect-your-server-information/

Is there any similar solution to remove request headers?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: It's all controllable by you. If you don't put it there, there will be nothing to remove.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat http://www.techstacks.com/howto/suppress-server-identity-in-tomcat.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102511/remove-server-header-tomcat ...

Comment: @Baadshah not like that. Note that there are response headers that you would like to omit. Refer to the link provided by OP and links in my comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : The link you have given suppresses header fields which are already existing(default headers). I am looking for a solution , where a user cannot intentionally add "dummy" headers when requesting my page. How do i suppress that?

Comment: That's not what I understood from your problem. Anyway, I guess you could do it in a servlet filter.