# How to Hide Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD and server name in tomcat response

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

```
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 26 May 2017 12:05:36 GMT
< Server: myservername
```

Hi whenever i do a curl request to my application using HTTP TRACE method . The above response displays .

Can someone tell me the steps to hide the "Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD" and "Server: myservername" information. How to hide these two in my TOMCAT6

Comment: there could be a better option.. but you can try removing the header using a filter

Answer (score 1):

By default Tomcat automatically responds to TRACE requests with a status code 405 and the headers you showed.

To change this behaviour you can do the following:

- Allow TRACE requests to reach your servlets. This is done by settings the allowTrace attribute to true on a connector: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes
- In your servlet detect and handle the TRACE request and the send only the headers you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not take so much attention about that.

You launched a HTTP request with the method TRACE.
The answer tells you that method TRACE is not supported (Status 405) and provides available and supported method in the header `Allow : POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD`

All of this is perfectly acceptable and seems like a normal behaviour.

About the Server header, you have [some details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102511/remove-server-header-tomcat)