# Disable Apache Web Server Signature from displaying in browser

Tags: apache, silverstripe

We have a website that is built on Silverstripe / PHP / Apache Tomcat. For all valid requests, the redirections for Page not found and backend not available are working fine which are configured in .htacess.

Incase of **invalid** requests (there are some URLs generated by Silverstripe I guess), the redirection to error pages doesn't happen. In such case Apache Web Server Signature is displayed on the browser which can be used by an attacker to launch further attacks on the application.

We have tried below settings but no luck

In Apache Config file:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Happy to share more details if required.

Thanks!

Comment: have you restarted the server after making the config changes?

Comment: Yes I did restart it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove server header tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102511/remove-server-header-tomcat)

Comment: Quick look into documentation, `ServerSignature Off` is for Apache Web Server instead of Tomcat.